# How to restore windows 7 acronis backup when ubuntu is installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, backup

I have windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 both installed on my machine (Dual boot). I frequently backup my windows C drive with acronis backup utility in case something happens and I can not access my windows. I made a bootable media(on my 16GB flash) to restore my backups(on my external hard drive) with that. I used this method before I installed ubuntu many times. But now I can not boot acronis backup tools with my flash and I get this message:

```
Remove disks or other media
Press any key to restart
```

I think this is because of ubuntu installed on my D drive (I have only 2 partitions). Any ideas on how to restore my acronis windows backups when ubuntu is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I used Acronis as well.  It doesn't have a problem doing drive backups and restorations when you have Linux installed.

In fact their CD version will backup the entire disk and it uses Linux to do that.  You could also use a awesome whole disk backup solution that is free called clonezilla.  I realize that doesn't do backups while you are using your system though like Acronis, but it does great otherwise.

Your flash drive might just be corrupted.  Ubuntu will not effect booting into your Flash drive AT ALL.

If you hit the proper bios key you can boot directly to that device.  Once you do so if it doesn't load Acronis you might wanna try reinstalling on that device by first wiping it to FAT and then reinstalling.  Or if you have the option to just burn a CD you could do that as well.

Or if you don't want to fuss with it just install clonezilla it does the same thing and can backup partitions to image files and can restore them to disk, or even different disks.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me some clues about the issue. The fact that ubuntu does not have anything to do with booting from flash is a huge relief.  Now I just have to find a way to fix this booting problem. Bootable media is bunch of files acronis generated and I have it on my external hard drive. Everytime I needed to restore I just copied those files to my flash and boot from it and restore to backups. But the copying process was done on some other windows machine. This is the first time I'm copying those files from ubuntu. Do you think maybe file permissions is what causing the problem?

Comment: What file format are those files stored in?  Have you look at that yet?